# build notification in visual Studio 2008\2010 - WMI etc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, events, compiler-construction, wmi

I want to be notified when a build has been completed\failed in visual studio and I DO NOT want to use pre\post build steps, I want an external process or VS plugin that will count the number of builds.

So is there anyway to achieve this using something like WMI or other such technology?

I'm not interested in third party libaries, I want to write a plugin for visual studio.

Comment: You want to write your own vs plugin which shows no. of build and there status. Is this you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't. You can either use the pre/post build steps, or make an add-in. For the latter look for `EnvDTE.BuildEvents`. Let me know if you need a sample.

Any particular reasons you don't want to use the pre/post build steps, you can pretty much do anything with them, i.e. send mail, increment the file version information in AssemblyInfo etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [TFS PowerToys for 2008 or 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/bb980963.aspx) includes a build notification tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this free VS plugin for Build status.

You can find it [**here**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/2A2293B4-1808-44AA-B030-661F6803D8A1).